# The insert function seems to be inheriting the read-only property

Tags: text-properties, insert

I'trying to insert a row of characters into a buffer, where the first four characters should be read-only. Here's the relevant part of the code :

```el
(insert (propertize "cn) " 'read-only t))
(insert (propertize (format "%s\n" hanzi) 'face 'kaiti-red))
```

When this code is run, I get a *"Text is read-only"* message, the buffer holds just the "cn) " string, read-only as expected, but nothing can be inserted after.

It seems that the second 'insert' is inheriting the read-only property, even though the "Stickiness of Text Properties" node in the emacs lisp manual says "The ordinary text insertion functions, such as insert, do not inherit any properties."

Can someone please explain what's going on here ? I'm using Emacs 26.2 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is intentional according to `read-only`'s info manual [(info "(elisp) Special Properties")](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html):

> `read-only`
>
> Insertion next to a read-only character is an error if inserting
>   ordinary text there would inherit the `read-only` property due to
>   stickiness. Thus, you can control permission to insert next to
>   read-only text by controlling the stickiness. See [Sticky
>   Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sticky-Properties.html#Sticky-Properties).
>
> Since changing properties counts as modifying the buffer, it is not
>   possible to remove a `read-only` property unless you know the special
>   trick: bind `inhibit-read-only` to a non-`nil` value and then remove
>   the property. See [Read Only
>   Buffers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Read-Only-Buffers.html#Read-Only-Buffers).

As it says, when insert text next a read-only character, we does get a
`text-read-only` error:

```el
(condition-case err
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert (propertize "hello" 'read-only t) "world"))
  (text-read-only (error-message-string err)))
;; => "Text is read-only"
```

To work-around this, the above info manual suggests two options. The first
option is by controlling the stickiness, for example, we set `rear-nonsticky` to
`(read-only)` to disable inheriting only the `read-only` text property, you can
also set it to `t` to disable inheriting all text properties:

```el
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert (propertize "hello" 'read-only t 'rear-nonsticky '(read-only))
          "world")
  (buffer-string))
;; => #("helloworld" 0 5 (rear-nonsticky (read-only) read-only t))
```

The second option is let-binding the `inhibit-read-only` variable, e.g.,

```el
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert (propertize "hello" 'read-only t))
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
    (insert "hello"))
  (buffer-string))
;; => #("hellohello" 0 5 (read-only t))
```

Comment: I still think there's a problem with the documentation. The part
you quoted says that we should expect to get the read-only error if the
insertion _"would inherit the read-only property due to stickiness"_, and the
part I quoted says that the insert function does _not_ inherit, that's a clear
contradiction.

But anyway, your workaround really solved my problem, so I was more than
happy to accept your answer.

Comment: OP: If you think the doc could use some improvement then please submit an enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.